# Derivative of anti-self-dual forms on Kähler space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, differential-forms

I am puzzled if we can establish differential relations about anti-self-dual 2-forms on the Kähler space similar to ones for self-dual forms?

Let $(\mathcal{M},g,J,\omega = J^{(1)})$ be a Kähler space. We will pick the orientation such that the Kähler form $J^{(1)}$ is self-dual. Then it is known that the covariant derivatives of self-dual forms satisfy a set of simple relations.

Denote by $J^{(i)}$, $i=1,2,3$ a basis on the space of self-dual 2-forms $\Omega^+(\mathcal{M})$. Then the following two facts are known:

- We can further specify a basis on $\Omega^2(\mathcal{M})$ that satisfies quaternionic algebra relations
  \begin{equation}
  J^{(i)\,p}_{m} J^{(j)}_{\quad p n} = -\delta^{ij}\, J^{(i)}_{mn} + \epsilon^{ijk} \,J^{(k)}_{mn}.
  \tag{1}\label{1}
  \end{equation}
  In fact we can always locally pick such a basis for any four-dimensional Riemann manifold.
- The covariant derivatives of $J^{(i)}$ are
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
  &\nabla_X J^{(1)} = 0\\
  &\nabla_X J^{(2)} = P(X) J^{(3)}\\
  &\nabla_X J^{(3)} = - P(X) J^{(2)}
  \end{aligned}
  \tag{2}\label{2}
  \end{equation}
  where $X\in T\mathcal{M}$ and $P\in \Omega^1(\mathcal{M})$ is the Ricci potential: $\mathcal{R} = d P$.

---

Now similarly denote by $I^{(i)}$, $i=1,2,3$ a basis on the space of anti-self-dual 2-forms $\Omega^-(\mathcal{M})$. Again, we can pick the basis to satisfy quaternionic-like relations
$$ I^{(i)\,p}_{m} I^{(j)}_{\quad p n} = -\delta^{ij}\, I^{(i)}_{mn} - \epsilon^{ijk} \,I^{(k)}_{mn}.$$
**Are there similar nice relations for** $\nabla_X I^{(i)}$ **?**

---

P.S. Since I have never seen a proof of \eqref{2} in the literature, I will sketch it here.
First of all, notice from \eqref{1} that $J^{(2)}, J^{(3)}$ are anti-J-invariant forms. In fact, they are the only anti-J-invariant 2-forms, as all ASD forms (and, obviously, $J^{(1)}=J$) are J-invariant. We can then define J-conjugation $\phi: \beta(X,Y)\mapsto \beta(JX,JY)$ which is an automorphism of $\Omega^2(\mathcal{M})$ which commutes with covariant derivative
$$\phi (\nabla_X \beta) = \nabla_X \phi (\beta).$$
Consequently, the covariant derivative of $J^{(2)}, J^{(3)}$ must be a section of $T^*(\mathcal{M}) \times \Omega^{(-J)}(\mathcal{M})$, where the latter is spanned by $J^{(2)}, J^{(3)}$.
Furthermore, notice that $$J^{(i) mn} \nabla_X J^{(j)}_{mn}= - J^{(j) mn} \nabla_X J^{(i)}_{mn}$$ which implies that
\begin{align*}
&\nabla_X J^{(2)} = k(X) J^{(3)}\\
&\nabla_X J^{(3)} = - k(X) J^{(2)}
\end{align*}
for some 1-form $k$. It can be found from integrability constraint
$$J^{(3)pq}[\nabla_m,\nabla_n] J^{(2)}_{pq} = 4 \mathcal{R}_{mn} = 4 (dk)_{mn}.$$
Using $\mathcal{R}= dP$ we find that $k=P$ up to a closed form.

Comment: Your post referenced (1) and (2) but did not seem to define them, so I guessed at what seemed to be the most sensible definition.  I hope that it was correct.

Comment: Thank you! Your correction is right. I did not know that you have to do `\tag{1}` for numeration in MathJax